# Bash Script Output to console and file

Tags: linux, bash, grep, tee

I need a small script to search for a string in log files and count the numbers of lines. Because this may take i while, i also want the output of "grep" shown in console. my idea is something like:

```
grep -irl "System out of memory" | tee /tmp/checkoom.tmp
COUNT=(cat /tmp/checkoom.tmp |wc -l)
echo $COUNT logs found.
```

But it dont works. I dont get any output, the tmp file is created but seems to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to provide the starting directory fro your search:

```
grep -irl "System out of memory" <somewhere> | tee /tmp/checkoom.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one liner for getting usb records from /var/log/messages:

```
echo "$(grep -i '/lib/udev/usb' /var/log/messages > ~/yourFile ; cat ~/yourFile | wc -l ) logs found"
```

Hope you find it usefull

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in the script:

- The path to grep
- $() is used to execute a command. This has to be added when assigning variable COUNT

Updated script:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -irl "System out of memory" <path to search> | tee /tmp/checkoom.tmp
COUNT=$(cat /tmp/checkoom.tmp | wc -l)
echo "$COUNT" logs found.
```

Also you could use the -F option in grep. -F stands for Fixed Strings

Comment: Strange, it still dont works. If i use the grep command without | tee, evrything is doing fine ...

Comment: This should work in normal case. Try using "find". Butgrep is the right option :) 

Try using the command >> #find <path to search> -type f -exec grep -irl "System out of memory" {} \; > /tmp/checkoom.tmp